# Deny direct access to any files in a folder using apache/php

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, apache, lamp

This might seem like a duplicate question but I have tried the solution given in the similar questions.

I want to limit access to files in a few folders on my apache server so that they can only be served through a php script to only the users logged in to the part of my system that should have access to any particular folder.

Other solutions suggest using the .htaccess

```
deny from all
allow from 127.0.0.1
```

But that seems to deny the files from everywhere.Including the local php scripts.

Im considering .htpasswd but that is an extra level of user credentials that needs to be handeled and I'd prefere to avoid that.

How should I get around this? Is there any better way of storing the files?

Comment: the above solution should work. unless your local scripts are doing something 'weird' (accessing local files over http for example)

Comment: I know that is what I expected too. But when I call <?php include('file.php')?> it obviously doesn't read it. And I dont think an include could be considered a very weird thing to do.

Comment: The `.htaccess` option is what you want. It will deny the entire directory, including the script you want to serve them through if it's in there. The solution to that is to move the script somewhere else

Comment: Can't you just move the files out of the web-root? That seems like the obvious solution for files that can only be served via php scripts.

Comment: something else must be going on here.

Comment: I would have moved them out of the web root if I was allowed to. But the hotel Im on is not giving me that opportunity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow php was restricted by the

```
deny from all
allow from 127.0.0.1
```

to include and require files in the affected folders. This goes against what I can read from the apache documentation how this should work and I have no real answer why. The problem persisted both on my localhost using Xampp and on the webhotel one.com.

My original question was badly formed since I used require to test if I had read access to the folder when I actually wanted to use readfile.

My main concern was that I wanted to serve files for download from an inaccessible directory. 
And the

```
readfile($filename);
```

could still access the files.

The soultion to this problem was that I realized that readfile() and include() somhow gets different permissions. I could not find this in any documentation.

Answer (score 0):

htaccess cannot deny access to files via php using include/require functions. If your php include is not accessing the file then the problem is the path to the file.

Comment: Still the include works when I remove the deny from .htaccess. Cant explain the reasons and I would love to know if there is any error output that can show me what is going on.